# I've been get error code:1064 sintaxys mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'been watching this error but i don't find nothing

CODE:

```
SELECT sv.id, sv.service_state_id as sstId, sha.id, sha.address, sha.user_guide as guide, sha.users_id, sst.id
FROM deliver_db_v2.service as sv
inner join deliver_db_v2.service_has_address as sha
inner join deliver_db_v2.service_state as sst
on sv.id = sha.users_id
on sv.sstId = sst.id;
```

Error:

> SELECT sv.id, sv.service_state_id as sstId, sha.id, sha.address, sha.user_guide as guide, sha.users_id, sst.id FROM deliver_db_v2.service as sv inner join deliver_db_v2.service_has_address as sha inner join deliver_db_v2.service_state as sst on sv.id = sha.users_id on sv.sstId = sst.id    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on sv.sstId = sst.id' at line 6    0.094 sec

Comment: Your title says you're using MySQL Workbench but you've used the phpMyAdmin tag, which one is it you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the `ON` clause of the first inner join.

You can do:

```
SELECT
  sv.id, sv.service_state_id as sstId, sha.id, sha.address,
  sha.user_guide as guide, sha.users_id, sst.id
FROM deliver_db_v2.service as sv
inner join deliver_db_v2.service_has_address as sha on sv.id = sha.users_id
inner join deliver_db_v2.service_state as sst on sv.sstId = sst.id;
```

Each `INNER JOIN` must have its own `ON` clause.